# Transparent PNG doesn't appear transparent in WordPress site

Tags: html, css, png, transparent

I have created buttons with PNG background images at https://hbccc.org/services-we-provide/ but the image backgrounds are white instead of transparent.

Following suggestions in similar problems, I have examined all the higher containers with Inspector and verified that the next higher container with a background color is my page background .

I copied the html, css and images to a new html page at https://mountainviewpm.com/button-test.html and they display properly.
Button images were created as transparent 8-bit PNG in Fireworks and confirmed that the buttons and images display properly there.

Here's the html for the page with one button (the other buttons are identical except for text and background image):

```
<div class="services-container">
  <a href="https://hbccc.org/childrens-counseling/">
  <button class="service-button" id="children" type="button">Children's Counseling</button></a> 
</div>
```

Here's the css for the container and button:

```
.services-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 900px;
  max-width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 -11px;
}

.service-button {
  font-family: 'Amiko', sans-serif;
  color: #414141;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  background-color: transparent !important;
  padding: 90px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 229px;
  height: 232px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 20px 11px;
}

#children {
  background-image: url(assets/images/childrens.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 30%;
}
```

I expect the background of the images to be the button background, not white.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just the background of your website. Can you also validate that this happens when you cleanly install wordpress without any aditional css?

Comment: Somehow the images you are trying to show have white background.
Are you sure you are uploading the correct images? I've never seen Wordpress changing the background color of images before.

Comment: It's your button background, not image background. Try setting button background-color to transparent

Comment: @EvgeniiMalikov No, it's not. Just open any of the images. They have white background

Comment: You mean first example? They're different, really have white background. Try to upload images using ftp.

Comment: Thank you @EvgeniiMalikov and @Azametzin! Turns out there are two sets of images uploaded, one transparent and one not transparent and I had linked to the wrong set without realizing it.